# Add hash to images in css webpack

Tags: css, webpack

Is there a way to add hash values to images that are referenced in CSS when you compile using Webpack?

I'm using React, and have separate scss files for each component file (e.g header.js & header.scss). Within some of the scss files, I have a background image. However, my server has super high caching levels, and is caching the images within the compiled css files.

What I'd like to do is, during the css compilation, add a hash value to each image reference, which would update on every build. So for example, it would compile to this:

```
.background-class {
  background-image: url('images/my-image.jpg?0adg83af0');
}
```

I've tried to use the url-loader, but because these images aren't being referenced in the JS files, I don't think they're being picked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of PostCSS and PostCSS CacheBuster. If anyone wants to add this to their webpack setup, you need to run `npm i postcss-loader postcss-cachebuster`, then in your webpack.config.js, add `const PostCssCacheBuster = require('postcss-cachebuster');` to the top of your file, and add the following loader config in between css-loader and sass-loader (obviously if you use this setup):

```
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              plugins: () => [
                PostCssCacheBuster({
                  imagesPath: "/src/Frontend",
                  cssPath: "/" + distributionPath,
                  supportedProps: [
                    'background',
                    'background-image'
                  ],
                  paramName: 'v='
                })
              ]
            }
          },
```